# Wine, but for mac .apps?

Tags: mac

Is there such a program like wine, but one that runs Mac / OSX `.app(s)`? I would find it very interesting to run mac `.apps` and see the result on such a program.

Answer (score 5):

Sadly no, although people are trying. See [www.darlinghq.org](http://www.darlinghq.org/)

[Similar Question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/6229/can-i-run-osx-applications)

[You could always run virtualized though...](https://askubuntu.com/questions/303725/virtualbox-how-to-install-os-x-guest-under-ubuntu-host)