# MacBook OS X Mavericks 10.9.5 installation on Oracle VM VirtualBox possible?

Tags: system-installation, virtualbox, macbook

I want to install Ubuntu (VM) on my MacBook OS X Mavericks 10.9.5  with processor 1.3 GHz,  is it possible in my system?

Comment: `Is my system too old?` How much RAM do you have? You can dual boot Ubuntu instead of virtualbox (for better performance). `Which version is possible?` For virtualbox, I would suggest a light flavor like Xubuntu or Lubuntu 22.04 LTS.

Comment: processors don't have "GB", it might be 1.3 GHz, though.

Comment: How much RAM do you have? Ubuntu will run in RAM if there is enough of it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [VirtualBox - How to install OS X guest under Ubuntu host?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/303725/virtualbox-how-to-install-os-x-guest-under-ubuntu-host)